# Alfresco saving version comments while editing in MS Office

Tags: alfresco

when uploading new version of document in Alfresco, you are able to add comment to this new version. Is it possible somehow to do the same when editing document online in MS Office?

I know there is properties mapping using AOS, but this doesn't make a comment when saving new revision. Or does it?

Does anybody know if this is possible or not?
Thanks in advance!!!